# Is it possible to control svg programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I need to create a conveyor belt animation that moves items on the conveyor belt in one direction as you scroll down the page and then does the reverse if you scroll back up again. I've found this example which is more or less what I need except rather than moving automatically it needs to be triggered by scrolling.

http://codepen.io/rezen/pen/vEgqs

Does anyone know how this could be modified to achieve this?

```
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewport-fill="#00A8A4" width="1200px" height="600px">
   <defs>
    <g id="file">

                <path fill="#FFFFFF" opacity=".2" d="M-11.605-11.518c-1.043,0-1.889,0.846-1.889,1.888v147.313c0,1.042,0.845,1.888,1.889,1.888H93.932
                    c1.044,0,1.89-0.846,1.89-1.888V13.191L71.111-11.518H-11.605z"/>

            <line opacity="0.3" fill="none" stroke="#00504B" stroke-width="5.9066" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="-13.494" y1="137.748" x2="95.822" y2="137.748"/>

            <line fill="none" stroke="#27BBB1" stroke-width="7.8755" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="-13.494" y1="-9.63" x2="62.041" y2="-9.63"/>

            <line opacity="0.3" fill="none" stroke="#00504B" stroke-width="5.9066" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="65.436" y1="24.866" x2="96.238" y2="24.866"/>

            <path fill="#27BBB1" stroke="#006B64" stroke-width="5.9066" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
            M96.527,20.167H63.929c-1.043,0-1.889-0.846-1.889-1.89v-29.795"/>

                <path fill="#004C47" d="M71.111-11.518l24.711,24.709v124.491c0,1.042-0.846,1.888-1.89,1.888H-11.605
                    c-1.043,0-1.889-0.846-1.889-1.888V-9.63c0-1.042,0.845-1.888,1.889-1.888H71.111 M71.111-17.424h-82.716
                    c-4.298,0-7.795,3.497-7.795,7.794v147.313c0,4.298,3.497,7.794,7.795,7.794H93.932c4.299,0,7.796-3.497,7.796-7.794V13.191
                    c0-1.566-0.622-3.069-1.729-4.177L75.288-15.694C74.179-16.802,72.677-17.424,71.111-17.424L71.111-17.424z"/>

    </g>
   <g id="wheel-form">
            <path fill="#004C47" d="M28.396,5.907c12.237,0,22.316,9.96,22.466,22.203c0.074,6.003-2.194,11.677-6.388,15.975
                    c-4.193,4.298-9.808,6.705-15.811,6.779l-0.285,0.002c-12.239,0-22.32-9.96-22.471-22.201
                    C5.756,16.269,15.716,6.062,28.11,5.909l0.285-0.002H28.396 M28.395,0c-0.119,0-0.239,0.001-0.357,0.002
                    C12.36,0.196-0.19,13.061,0.002,28.736c0.192,15.556,12.862,28.036,28.377,28.036c0.119,0,0.239-0.001,0.357-0.002
                    c15.674-0.192,28.226-13.058,28.032-28.732C56.577,12.479,43.907-0.001,28.395,0L28.395,0z"/>
            <circle fill="none" stroke="#003D38" stroke-width="11.8133" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="28.385" cy="28.384" r="9.91"/>
            <path opacity="0.47" fill="none" stroke="#00A79D" stroke-width="3.3441" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
            M39.432,28.353c0,6.101-4.947,11.047-11.046,11.047s-11.047-4.946-11.047-11.047"/>
        </g>

        <g id="spokes">

                <line fill="none" stroke="#00A8A4" stroke-width="3.3439" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="9.305" y1="28.621" x2="17.521" y2="28.52"/>

                <line fill="none" stroke="#00A8A4" stroke-width="3.3439" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="39.315" y1="28.25" x2="47.529" y2="28.15"/>

                <line fill="none" stroke="#00A8A4" stroke-width="3.3439" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="28.174" y1="8.628" x2="28.279" y2="17.122"/>

                <line fill="none" stroke="#00A8A4" stroke-width="3.3439" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="28.557" y1="39.649" x2="28.662" y2="48.142"/>

            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate"  from="0, 28.5,28.5"  to="360 , 28.5,28.5" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </g>

        <path id="conveyer"  transform="translate(18, 18)" fill="none" stroke="#002A25"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M893.69,28.622c0,20.935-16.972,37.907-37.908,37.907H29.105c-20.935,0-37.907-16.973-37.907-37.907l0,0
        c0-20.937,16.972-37.908,37.907-37.908h826.677C876.719-9.287,893.69,7.685,893.69,28.622L893.69,28.622z">

        </path>
 </defs>
 <g id="conveyer-files" transform="translate(70, 46)">
    <g>
        <use  xlink:href="#file"></use>
        <text x="0" y="124"  style="font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:25px;fill:#004C47">
            HTML
        </text>
   </g>
   <g transform="translate(140, 0)">
        <use  xlink:href="#file"></use>
        <text x="0" y="124"  style="font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:25px;fill:#004C47">
            CSS
        </text>
   </g>
   <g transform="translate(280, 0)">
        <use  xlink:href="#file"></use>
        <text x="0" y="124"  style="font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:25px;fill:#004C47">
            JS
        </text>
   </g>

  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" from="70, 46" to="710, 46" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

 </g>
 <g id="conveyer-full" transform="translate(20, 200)">
    <g transform="translate(20, 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(111.5 , 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(203 , 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(294.5 , 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(386, 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(477.5 , 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(569, 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(660.5 , 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(752 , 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(843.5, 18)">
        <use  xlink:href="#wheel-form"/>
        <use  xlink:href="#spokes"/>
    </g>


    <use  xlink:href="#conveyer" stroke-width="7" />
    <use  xlink:href="#conveyer" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="12,12" >
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="600;0" begin="0s" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </use>
</g>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, but in your case you'd probably have to modify/adapt the original conveyor belt's SVG definition. I normally use a very nice Javascript library for programmatically manipulating SVG graphics: [svgjs](http://www.svgjs.com/)

See an example of animation here: http://www.svgjs.com/clock/